# Redirect after post deleted

Tags: filters, actions, single

On the single template, I am using a delete post link generated by the get_delete_post_link function. When I use the link to delete the post I am currently on, it adds a query string of ?trashed=1&ids=10, but, as expected, the page generates a 404 error as that post is now gone. I'm just wondering if anyone knows an action/filter I can use to detect when the post has been deleted, so I re-direct the page somewhere else afterwards? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you use the hook `deleted_post` and create a rewrite. The hook runs just after a post or page is deleted. Action function arguments is post- or page-ID.

Comment: Thanks, this pointed me in the right direction. Turns out, as I was sending them to the trash, hooking trashed_post worked a treat. Only problem I seem to now be facing is that I only want it to fire on the single template, but if I add if(is_single()), it fails to re-direct :(